# In Oracle SQL Developer, I am unable to create table due to duplicate columns into same table

Tags: oracle

I am unable to create table due to duplicate columns into same table.
There is duplicate column name called load_Tstamp. How to rename the column or any other alternative?

```
Create table New_County_code as (
   Select a.*,b.LOAD_TSTMP as Load_time
   from (
      Select CONCAT( b.STATE_FIPS_CODE,a.ZIP_CNTY_CDE) AS "Final_County_Code",
      a.*,
      b.*
      from  mdmstggeo.T_USPS_DETAIL_RECORD@ODSDEV a
      left join  (
         select * 
         from DSSCORP.T_STATE@ds31 
         where STATE_FIPS_CODE is not  null) b  
      on ST_CPTL_BLDG_ZIP_CDE = DTL_ZIP_CDE
      WHERE ds_batch_gid=1661 
      order by STATE_FIPS_CODE 
    )
  )
```

Comment: Alias one of them to a different name.

Comment: Don't create the table?

Comment: Still shows the error  by using alias method ORA-00904: "B": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: I thought that duplicate column name is quite straightforward error text and as long as you've already provided an alias to one of your expressions, you actually know the solution

Answer (score 0):

Every column name in your target table must be unique, so use column aliases wherever needed to ensure that

```
SQL> create table t1 as
  2  select a.*, b.*
  3  from scott.dept a,
  4       scott.dept b;
select a.*, b.*
              *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00957: duplicate column name


SQL>
SQL> create table t1 as
  2  select a.*, b.deptno c1, b.dname c2, b.loc c3
  3  from scott.dept a,
  4       scott.dept b;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL>  desc t1
 Name                                                                    Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- --------------
 DEPTNO                                                                           NUMBER(2)
 DNAME                                                                            VARCHAR2(14)
 LOC                                                                              VARCHAR2(13)
 C1                                                                               NUMBER(2)
 C2                                                                               VARCHAR2(14)
 C3                                                                               VARCHAR2(13)
```